# How to prove that for $- x\log{(x)}\le\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, exponential-function, epsilon-delta

Where the $\log$ is the natural log of $x$. It is only required for the interval $(0,1)$.

I tried square both side (since both of them are positive) 
 $ x^2\log^2{(x)}\le x$ , which implies  $ x\log^2{(x)}\le 1$. However, I have no clue how to proceed from here. I also tried solve it in exponential form, which would be $e^{(- x\log{(x)})} = x^{-x} \le e^{\sqrt{x}}$, but don't know how to move on from here as well...

In addition, I do think differentiating $x\log{(x)}+\sqrt{x}$ would help at all since even if it can be proved that it is an increasing function for all $x>0$, I still cannot conclude that $- x\log{(x)}$ is strictly less than $\sqrt{x}$ since the domain of $x\log{(x)}+\sqrt{x}$ is an open interval

Comment: it's meant to be prove that x*ln(x)<=sqrt(x)

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: What have you attempted thus far? If you have made some effort, please show us. That way, we can acquire a better understanding of your skill level and make our answers more appropriate.

Comment: @K.Livingston Can you prove that $x \ln x ≤ 0$ for $0 < x < 1$?

Comment: @Toby Mak Yeah that's obvious since ln(x)<0 and 0<x<1 for 0<x<1, xlnx≤0